# Spring boot application not accepting large image files as Multipartfile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have setup a controller POST function to accept 2 object, 1 normal object/JSON, and an image file. When submitting a FormData object from my Angular application it will send a POST request to my Spring application, when selecting an image file of about 1 MB it would work as expected, but when sending a imagine file of about 3-4 MB the application would throw an exception. But, I have this `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB` on my application.properties. I also leave my CORS configuration below:

Post function:

```
    @PostMapping("/post")
    public void postPicture(@RequestPart("pictureDetails") PictureDetailsDto picturePostDto,
                            @RequestPart("inpFile") MultipartFile image,
                            HttpServletRequest request) {
        pictureService.postPicture(picturePostDto, image, request);
    }
```

Angular HttpClient function:

```
  postPicture(picturePostDto: PicturePostDto, pictureImage: File | null) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    const picturePart = new Blob([JSON.stringify(picturePostDto)], {
      type: 'application/json',
    });
    formData.append('pictureDetails', picturePart);

    if (pictureImage != null) {
      formData.append('inpFile', pictureImage)
    }

    const options = {
      withCredentials: true, // Include cookies in the request
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/picture/post`, formData, options);
  }
```

CorsConfiguration beam:

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1179) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:596) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:336) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:131) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:954) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:858) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:106) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2790) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2691) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:774) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:315) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:315) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:315) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:86) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:112) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1219) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:563) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at com.david.caterest.config.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: It's an `EOFException`. I doubt it has to do with the file type. More likely it's the file size or some in-between network configuration that decides to drop the connection.

Comment: 1) Check out the timeout configuration in angular http.post
2) Make sure you have not already consumed the file stream.

Comment: You are right, I tried to upload a smaller JPG image and it worked. I am trying multiple things on my application.properties and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

EOF errors are usually due to file size, check the upload file size limitations in your application. Make sure this limit fits your application's needs